# Replace collections in Tree implementatnion

Tags: java, arrays, tree

I have a Tree implementation but i want change ArrayList to simply array, i don't want use collection in java i just want use array but i don't know how i can replace ArrayList to simply array.
There is a code:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private String data = null;
    private List<TreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
    int topSize;// I added it, since i know how is the size of Tree
    private TreeNode[] children2 = new TreeNode[topSize];//I added it
    private TreeNode parent = null;

    public TreeNode(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    int i = 0;//I added it

    public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
        this.children2[i++] = child;//I added it
    }

    public void addChild(String data) {
        TreeNode newChild = new TreeNode(data);
        newChild.setParent(this);
        children.add(newChild);
        children2[i] = newChild;// I added it
    }

    public void addChildren(List<TreeNode> children) {
        for (TreeNode t : children) {
            t.setParent(this);
        }
        this.children.addAll(children);

    }

    public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Root");

        TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("Child1");
        child1.addChild("Grandchild1");
        child1.addChild("Grandchild2");

        TreeNode child2 = new TreeNode("Child2");
        child2.addChild("Grandchild3");

        root.addChild(child1);
        root.addChild(child2);
        root.addChild("Child3");

        root.addChildren(Arrays.asList(
                new TreeNode("Child4"),
                new TreeNode("Child5"),
                new TreeNode("Child6")
        ));
        TreeNode mainRoot = new TreeNode("MainRoot");
        mainRoot.addChildren(Arrays.asList(root));

        for (TreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(node.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

I create TreeNode[] children2 array and add int topSize, since i know what size tree will be.But it doesn't work correctly. I want Tree without collections from java.java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   in     children2[i] = newChild;

Comment: What problem do you face? 'It does not work correctly' is a bit too vague.

Comment: I have :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  in children2[i] = newChild;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `topSize` variable is never assigned in our code, so it has the default value: `0`. This means that `children2` is an empty array. That's why you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while putting something into it.

Try to initialize `topSize` with some value, for example:

```
int topSize = 10;
```

After this modification, your program runs with no exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, now it work's, can you tell me why it doesn't work when i try set topSize like this: ` public Tree(String data, int topSize) {
        this.data = data;
        this.topSize = topSize;
    }` and in main `int topSize = 10;
     Tree root = new Tree("Root",topSize);`

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. As for the second question, try `Tree root = new Tree("Root",10);`

Comment: I try but it doesn't work i have: ~`int topSize  ;
 Tree[] children2 = new Tree[topSize];
    private Tree parent = null;
    public Tree(String data, int topSize) {
        this.data = data;
        this.topSize = topSize;
    }~` and in main : `Tree root = new Tree("Root",10);
     Tree child1 = new Tree("Child1",10);
     child1.addChild("Grandchild1");
     child1.addChild("Grandchild2");

     Tree child2 = new Tree("Child2",10);
     child2.addChild("Grandchild3");

     root.addChild(child1);
     root.addChild(child2);
     root.addChild("Child3");`

Comment: And i have error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in         children2[i++] = newChild;

Comment: @grapexs, I would recommend to you to use some debug technique. Any decent Java IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans) has a built-in debugger with which it is very easy to trace your program step by step and see what exactly happens during its execution.